# How to setup 2 actions with the same name, 1 Authorized and 1 not Authorized?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possble to have something like this in ASP.NET MVC...

```
[Authorize]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public string AddData(string Issues, string LabelGUID)
{
    return "Authorized";
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public string AddData()
{
    return "Not Authorized";
}
```

So if the user is not logged in, it defaults to the un-Authorized action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, its possible.  You would need to create your own `ControllerActionInvoker` and override the `FindActionMethod` member.  I'd let the base class do it's work and then check to see if the method it returns satisfies your criteria and if not, return a better match.

I'm doing something like this to allow my Controllers to have a "Default Action" and it works well.  Check out MvcContrib and their implementation of their ActionInvoker for a really nice example.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so. The controller action with the best parameter match will get selected and then the attributes will be applied.

You could use

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{  
    return "Authorized";
}
else
{  
    return "Not Authorized";
}
```

Under the hood [Authorize] is essentially doing the same thing

```
protected virtual bool AuthorizeCore(IPrincipal user)
{
    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
    }

    if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return false;
    }

    ...snip...
}
```